# make bootstrap alert disappear automatically

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have a form whch sends data to the databse, after data is sent successfully i want to show success msg, but i dont want it to stay rather to disappear after a short while.

```
$nameErr=$drug_idErr=$priceErr=$quantityErr=$dateErr=$dateInvalid="";

$drug_id=$name=$price=$quantity=$date="";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$drug_id=mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_POST['drug_id']));
$name=mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_POST['name']));
$price=mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_POST['price']));
$quantity=mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_POST['quantity']));
$date=mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_POST['date']));


    if(empty($drug_id)){
        $drug_idErr="Required";

        }
    elseif(empty($name)){
        $nameErr="Required";

        }
    elseif(empty($price)){
        $priceErr="Required";
        }

    elseif(empty($quantity)){
        $quantityErr="Required";
        }

    elseif(empty($date)){
        $dateErr="Required";
        }
    elseif(!preg_match('/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/', $date)){

        $dateInvalid="Invalid date format";
        }
    else{

        //send data to database here
        $_SESSION['success']="Drug added successfully";
        $drug_id=$name=$price=$quantity=$date="";


        }

}
```

the following is my form

```
<div class="well">
      <form id="register-form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <legend>Add new drug</legend>
        <?php  if(!empty($_SESSION['success'])){ 
         echo '<div class="alert alert-success">'.$_SESSION['success'].'</div>'; unset($_SESSION['success']);} ?>


        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">ID</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="drug_id" name="drug_id" placeholder="Drug ID"
                     value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($drug_id); ?>">
                </div>
                 <span class="error"><?php echo $drug_idErr;?></span>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="control-group ">
            <label class="control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-pills"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Drug Name"
                    value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name)?>">  
               </div>
               <span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Price</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-dollars"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-small" id="price" name="price" placeholder="Drug Price"
                    value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($price); ?>">
                </div>
                 <span class="error"><?php echo $priceErr; ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Quantity</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" id="quantity" class="input-mini" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity"
                    value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($quantity);?>">
                </div>
                 <span class="error"><?php echo $quantityErr;?></span>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Expire Date</label>
            <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>

           <td><input type="text" name="date"  id="date"   class="span2" placeholder="Expire date" 
           value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($date); ?>"/>
            </div>
              <span class="error"><?php  echo  $dateErr.$dateInvalid; ?></span>
     </div>
       </div>


        <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label"></label>
          <div class="controls">

           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" >Add</button>

          </div>

    </div>

      </form>

   </div>
```

now i can just show the alert but i don knw how to make it disappear

Comment: Have you seen jquery's fadeout function? http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.alert').hide()
```

Or you could use fading:

```
$('.alert').fadeOut(300)
```